# Why does my scrollbar react so slowly on IE?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, dom, knockout.js

I've written a few web controls (source code at https://rawb.codeplex.com/ ), among them a high-performance data grid for use with [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).  There's a demo page at http://www.spannerjs.com/Rawb/index.html .

Under Chrome and Firefox, the grid demo runs as smooth as silk when scrolling the grid vertically.  Under IE11, at least on Windows 8, vertically scrolling the grid is incredibly choppy -- the frame rate drops to about 4 FPS.  This is odd, because if you focus on the grid (e.g., by clicking on a row) then hold down the *down arrow* key, you can see how quickly and fluidly the grid can scroll under IE11.

I've tried examining the phenomenon with the IE11 profiler and UI responsiveness tools, but have been unable to work out why scrolling using the mouse should be so poor.  I should point out that the scrollbars are hand-coded (i.e., not browser-default scrollbars) -- the key function is `self.drag` in the `ScrollBar` class in the file `Rawb\js\rawb.ui.js`.

If anyone could offer advice on how to solve the problem, I would be immensely grateful.

**EDIT -- SOLVED**

It seems that IE11 (at least) doesn't like to interleave event handling code with rendering when there is a queue of events awaiting processing.  The fix was to throttle updates to the observable behind the scroll bar, limiting updates to 50 Hz.  This fixes the problem across the board.

Comment: I don't suppose "because it's IE" is a valid or useful answer?

Comment: 'Fraid not -- in most regards IE11 feels blazingly fast to me.

Comment: Random thought: do you have any conditional comments for CSS that I'm not seeing? IE11 doesn't honor those

Comment: @MarkB -- no, the CSS is completely vanilla in that regard.

Comment: If you choose to go the route of throttling the events like @Rafe suggested, you might want to consider this simple script.  [limit.js](https://github.com/m-gagne/limit.js).  Works like a charm and lightweight.